Can light interfere with itself?
Say I pointed a laser at a mirror such that the laser beam was reflected directly back in the direction it came from. What happens to the light on its way back? Does it interfere with the oncoming light, or are they able to "coexist" in the same space? Could I use some sort of optical device, like a beam splitter, to extract only the "returning" light from the beam?

It depends on the power of the source, reflecting back to it the source may blow up or just dissipates it. The situation is no different from short circuiting a battery or the ends of a transmission line. It is a heat dissipation rate problem.

Light does self-interfere. This is how laser interferometers work - a laser beam is split with, well, a beam splitter into two "legs"; each leg is reflected back into the beam splitter so the beams "merge" (i.e. interfere with each other), and measuring the phase difference between the two beams allows extremely precise distance measurements, so precise as to allow the detection of gravitational waves.
I am not an expert in optics exactly, but I have worked with interferometers before. If you were to do what you suggest then I suppose there are some configurations where the light beams interact perfectly-destructively and disappear, as well as some where they interact perfectly-constructively.

Yes, the same coherent sources of light rays do often interfere with themselves. This phenomenon is actually known as Diffraction of Light!
To understand what happens to light if you perfectly reflect it back on a plane mirror, you must first understand that to observe interference you must need a screen. A mirror here won't act like a screen and your eyes must directly be in line with the light ray with no parallax error. So practically the light source, your eye and the screen must be perfectly inline with each other which is hard to imagine.
But theoretically, I believe that (if ever observed at the point of incidence) it would indeed cause destructive interference since the light incident is perfectly reflected back. When a light ray reflects off a surface where the second medium is optically denser (like a mirror, metal, or glass), the reflected wave undergoes a phase change of  radians (or 180°). This would cause the reflected ray to "flip" and be out of phase with the incident ray.


Light reflecting in this way does not destructively interfere in the way your diagram suggests. It forms a standing wave.
